# MySQL dump exports only 100 mb

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 8 installed on AWS EC2 instance.

The instance is consuming more than 100GB of disk space which is mostly occupied by database backup files but the database itself has only approximately 300 MB of data.

Now before deleting the backup files to recover disk space, I want to take dump of the database first.

First I tried using the `mysqldump` command from the console

```
mysqldump -u root -p my_database > backup.sql
```

But it only exports 85MB of data.

Then I tried using DBeaver to create dump file, but it only exports 100MB of file which does not have all data.

I also tried adding the following configuration in the file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=500M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=1024M
```

But still cannot export more than 100MB.

How can I create dump of the entire database of 300MB+?

Comment: For what it's worth the `max_allowed_packet` is for inserting data, not retrieving.

Comment: Remember, the size of the database includes indexes, which can be significant in size, and the size of the dump is *only data*. It is not uncommon for indexes to be 50-150% the size of the data. The best way to test here is to restore that backup, then check table `COUNT(*)` values, and do a thorough spot check on the data.

Comment: @tadman - Max packet length to send to or receive from the server : see https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/

Comment: @BerndBuffen Doesn't streaming mean that in practice you can receive a lot more data than that? I have encountered problems with bulk inserts exceeding the `max_allowed_packet`, but never on the retrieval side, even loading 100+GB tables.

Comment: sorry, if the dump generates e.g. 10000 rows with an INSERT, it may be that the total size of this INSERT row is longer than max packet . This can also e.g. done by large TEXT fields. I've had this myself and @tadman - only because the text fields in all rows were filled over time and the dump broke off as a result. I was able to solve this with the option that the dump makes an INSERT for each line.
I will test this tonight again and send you the result